# iScroll on div with dynamically added images

Tags: iphone, cordova, iscroll

I'm using PhoneGap to create an iPhone application. I'm trying to use iScroll for the zoom functionality. But I'm having a problem where I cannot scroll until I zoom in on the div. Once I un-zoom the div then it's automatically scrolled back to the top.

I've looked at the following two threads that I thought would help but neither solution worked for my situation.

[Thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777156/making-iscroll-to-work-when-loading-a-div-dynamically)

[Thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/iscroll/a996K1VS0Bg)

I have a div that has images added to it after an AJAX call. I created a div wrapper around it that should be zoomable. The code for this is as followed

```
<div id = 'zoom-wrapper'>
    <div id="historyResponse"></div>
</div>
```

I have a JS function called showHistory() that has an AJAX call. On success images are added to the historyResponse div using .append().

After reading the two threads mentioned above I tried added things like myScroll.refresh() or destroying then recreating myScroll at the end of the JS function showHistory() but nothing fixed my problem.

Are there any other things I can try to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass this option `checkDOMChanges:true`. It helped me once to sort out similar problem when `myScroll.refresh()` failed.

**Something like this**

```
if('undefined' !== typeof myScroll){
   myScroll.destroy();
}

myScroll = new iScroll('<YOUR_ELEMENT_ID>', { checkDOMChanges:true });
```

**If you still face problem then try this**

```
if('undefined' !== typeof myScroll){
   myScroll.destroy();
}

myScroll = new iScroll('<YOUR_ELEMENT_ID>', { 
   checkDOMChanges:true, 
   onBeforeScrollStart : function(e){ 
      myScroll.refresh(); 
   } 
});
```

I hope at least one solution will help you. :)

Comment: Would I put this code inside the JS function where the images are being added?

Comment: at the place where you initialize **iScroll**